# Error: google.maps.number is not a constructor ,when rotation property is added to Icon or marker in google maps using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have added a customized icon to google maps and added rotation property to icon and when i run the code i get an error indicating " google.maps.number is not a constructor" can someone help me how to solve this problem.

```
var icon = {
url: 'newimage/unnamed.png', // url
scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25), // scaled size
origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
rotation: new google.maps.number(90)
};
//var myLatLng = {lat:50.8274, lng:12.9161};

var myLatLng = {lat:global_latlon.lat, lng:global_latlon.lng};
var test_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatLng,
map: map,
lat: myLatLng.lat,
lng: myLatLng.lng,
clickable: true,
name: 'test_marker', 
title: 'test_marker',
offset: 0,
icon: icon  

});
```

[image]

Comment: You should just use a number for rotation, e.g. `rotation: 90`

Comment: @user2314737 i used rotation: 90 and there was no error, but the icon is not rotating i.e the arrow still shows upwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving the error because there is no class called number which exists in **google.maps.number** package.

A google.maps.Icon has the following properties

```
anchor
labelOrigin 
origin 
scaledSize 
size 
url
```

Rotation is not one of them. Refer to the the [Google Map documentation : Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon) for further reference.

Comment: the "rotation" properties exists for Symbol, not for Icon.

Comment: Yes the rotation property exists for Symbol. However you cannot use a customised icon with Symbol.